# ejabberd external_auth didn't receive response

Tags: php, ejabberd

I have a problem with ejabberd 2.1.2 and **external_auth didn't receive response**.  I've checked all the different posts on google and the questions on here, and still have not found a resolution.

In my /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg I have the following entry:

```
{auth_method, external}.
{extauth_program, "/tmp/auth.php"}.
```

The extauth_program referenced above can be found below.  I can run the php file as the 'ejabberd' user and file creation / file permissions (log file too) are not a problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?
$fh  = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
$fs = fopen("/tmp/auth-log.txt." . getmypid(), 'a');

if(!$fh){
    die("Cannot open STDIN\n");
}

$users = array('user1'=>'password1', 'user2'=>'password2');

do{
    $lenBytes = fgets($fh, 3);
    $len = unpack('n', $lenBytes);
    $len = $len[1];
    if($len<1) continue;
    $msg = fgets($fh, $len+1);
    $toks=explode(':',$msg);
    fwrite($fs, $msg . "\n");

    $method = array_shift($toks);
    fwrite($fs, "$method\n");
    $result = false;

    switch($method){
        case 'auth':
            list($username, $server, $password) = $toks;
            $password = trim($password);
            fwrite($fs, "checking user: $username and password $password\n");

            if($users[$username] == $password){
                fwrite($fs, "password match\n");
                $result = true;
            }else{
                $result = false;
            }
            break;

        case 'isuser':
            list($username, $server) = $toks;
            if(isset($users[$username])){
                $result = true;
            }else{
                $result = false;
            }
            break;

        default:
            $result = false;
    }
        $message =  @pack("nn", 2, $result);
        fwrite($stdout, $message);
        $dump = @unpack("nn", $message);
        $dump = $dump["n"];
        fwrite($fs, $dump . "\n");
        flush();
} while(true);
?>
```

When I start xjabberd and attempt to connect with 'user1@example.com' and password:  'password1' it takes an incredibly long time, and eventually fails.  In the log file, I see the following entries generated from the above PHP script.  These occur almost instantly when the connection from client to server happens.

```
auth:user1:example.com:password1
auth
checking user: user1 and password password1
password match
2
```

In /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log I have the following entries:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:26 ===
I(<0.557.0>:ejabberd_c2s:587) : ({socket_state,tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.2820>,#Port<0.2844>},<0.556.0>}) Failed authentication for user1@example.com

=ERROR REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:36 ===
E(<0.365.0>:extauth:80) : extauth call '["auth","user1@example.com",
                                         "example.com","password1"]' didn't receive response

=INFO REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:36 ===
I(<0.559.0>:ejabberd_c2s:587) : ({socket_state,tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.2846>,#Port<0.2848>},<0.558.0>}) Failed authentication for user1@example.com@example.com

=INFO REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:37 ===
I(<0.553.0>:ejabberd_listener:232) : (#Port<0.2850>) Accepted connection {{10,1,1,3},55051} -> {{10,130,11,243},5222}

=ERROR REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:50 ===
E(<0.365.0>:extauth:80) : extauth call '["auth","user1","example.com",
                                         "password1"]' didn't receive response

=INFO REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:50 ===
I(<0.561.0>:ejabberd_c2s:587) : ({socket_state,tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.2850>,#Port<0.2852>},<0.560.0>}) Failed authentication for user1@example.com

=INFO REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:15:51 ===
I(<0.553.0>:ejabberd_listener:232) : (#Port<0.2854>) Accepted connection {{10,1,1,3},55052} -> {{10,130,11,243},5222}

=ERROR REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:16:03 ===
E(<0.365.0>:extauth:80) : extauth call '["auth","user1@example.com",
                                         "example.com","password1"]' didn't receive response

=INFO REPORT==== 2011-02-20 01:16:03 ===
I(<0.563.0>:ejabberd_c2s:587) : ({socket_state,tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.2854>,#Port<0.2856>},<0.562.0>}) Failed authentication for user1@example.com@example.com
```

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent 1 day trying to get work ejabberd authorization.
Problem basicly appears in blocking the process while reading from stdin. It is being kept blocked at the end of request string until client disconnects because of timeout.
Here is a solution for non-block symbol by symbol reading from descriptor:

```
function non_block_read($fd, &$data) {
    $read = array($fd);
    $write = array();
    $except = array();
    $result = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0);
    if($result === false) {
                throw new Exception('stream_select failed');
        }
    if($result === 0) return false;
    $data.= stream_get_line($fd, 1);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the daemon code also to make lifetime reading cycle.

```
$fh  = fopen("php://stdin", 'r');
$fhout  = fopen("php://stdout", 'w');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user,$pass);
if(!$fh){
    die("Cannot open STDIN\n");
}
$aStr='';
$collect=false;
do {
        if (!non_block_read($fh,$aStr)) {
                if (strlen($aStr) > 0) {
                       $toAuth = substr(trim($aStr),1);
                       checkAuth($toAuth,$pdo,$fhout);
                       $aStr='';
                }
                else sleep (1);
        }
}
while (true);
```

Some explaination: checkAuth - any function that implements 'auth' and 'isuser' handlers.
sleep(1) - simple way to escape CPU load.
First symbol - service symbol that prepends the message and it differs from client to client, so I just cut it.
Here is reply code. Reply - true | false values.

```
$message =  @pack("nn", 2, $result);
fwrite($stdout, $message);
flush();
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Before line:

```
$message =  @pack("nn", 2, $result);
```

Write:

```
$result = ($result) ? 1 : 0;
```